# Slackの投稿画面で、インデントを変更する方法はありますか？

Tags: slack

Slackで短いコードを貼り付けるときに ```**コードブロック**```  を使っています
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
すると画像のように、インデントがものすごく開いた状態になることがあります。
（ソースのインデントをそのまま引き継いでいる）

コードが扱えるテキストエディターであれば、範囲選択後に shift+tab で調整できますが、
Slackにおいてはどうもできないようです。

そのため、毎回delキーとbackキーで消す、spaceを挿入して調整する
という作業が必要です。
（今は他のテキストエディターを立ち上げて、調整後に貼り付けています）

エンジニア向けのSlackなので、もっとスムーズな方法があるのではないか？
この作業を無くす、軽減する方法があるのでは？と考えています。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「ソースのインデントをそのまま引き継いで」という事は、元のコードの時点でインデントされているということでしょうか？ (そうであれば既に実施しているように、貼り付け前にエディタ等で整えるしかなさそうです)

Comment: ありがとうございます。それしかなさそうですね。slackでインデントが調整できないことをとても不便に感じていました。しかし、そのこと触れた書き込みを全然見つけられません。そのため「実は機能としてはあるけど、知らないだけ」と考えて質問いたしました

Comment: 回答もないので、誰も余分なインデントは気にしていないことなのかもしれません…